# listview with imageview in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview

I am new with Android Studio, and I would like to try a listview with pictures on the left shown below. I managed to make such a list with a simple list item, but when I changed the simple item list with an ActivityList, it does not work anymore.

How can I change the ArrayList to combine imageviews with the names? I think it could be possible by using a new class which contains the imageview and name instead of strings.

[image: ActivityListView]

Code:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView friendsListView = findViewById(R.id.friendListView);
        final ArrayList<String> myFriends = new ArrayList<String>(asList("Mark","Jane","Sussy","Jan"));
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.activity_list_item
                , myFriends);
        friendsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        friendsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello " + myFriends.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use ListView, use RecyclerView. And also stay away form old tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, you need to create a model class for your list item; this model class contains things that differ from item to item; for instance in your shared picture, a list item has a typical of a picture and a title; and so your model class.

Next, instead of having `ArrayList<String>`, use `ArrayList<Item>`; where Item is the model class

Third, you need to create a custom adapter that extends from `ArrayAdapter<Item>`; that is because you can't use the built-in list item layout "android.R.layout.activity_list_item", because it just offers you with a single string; and now you need to accompany a picture with it.

Below is a simple demo

**Model class (Item.java)**

```
class Item {

    private int mPicture;
    private String mTitle;

    int getPicture() {
        return mPicture;
    }

    Item(int picture, String title) {
        mPicture = picture;
        mTitle = title;
    }

    String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

}
```

**List View Adapter (ListViewAdapter.java)**

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    ListViewAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<Item> items) {
        super(context, 0, items);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View listItem = convertView;
        if (listItem == null) {
            listItem = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        // Get the {@link Word} object located at this position in the list
        Item currentItem = getItem(position);

        ImageView picture = listItem.findViewById(R.id.IvPicture);
        picture.setBackgroundResource(currentItem.getPicture());

        TextView title = listItem.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        title.setText(currentItem.getTitle());

        return listItem;
    }

}
```

**Activity class**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

       @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.item1, "Item1"));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.item2, "Item2"));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.item3, "Item3"));

            ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, items);
            ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
}
```

**Activity Layout (activity_main.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**List item layout (list_item.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/IvPicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="item" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You have to have 3 images into res/drawable named item1, item2, and item3

Hope this satisfies your need.

Comment: Thank you. It helped. But I still have a question. I tried to implement it.  What do I have to wright here instead of dummylist in this line?  listItem = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dumy_list_item, parent, false); and I think there is still a problem with my code. Also in your xml you don't have a list view?  I think in my version is still something wrong. I will write it in the next comment.

Comment: You're welcome.. please tell me what you need to do @Tommy Supertramp

Comment: i added my code as new answer.  As Xml i used your code but with a list view in front of it

Comment: You can put your list view inside your activity layout xml file which you refer to in your activity class using setContentView() in onCreate()

Comment: @TommySupertramp please check my updated answer with all layout & java files ... please let me know if you need further help.. please note that the list item xml file is different from the activity xml file (which hosts your listview)

Answer (score 0):

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/grey_300"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

cards_layout.xml code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/color_white"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:tag="image_tag"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Android Name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewVersion"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                android:text="Android Version"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

menu_main.xml code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/add_item"
        android:title="Add"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

MainActivity.java

package com.journaldev.recyclerviewcardview;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private static RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private static ArrayList<DataModel> data;
    static View.OnClickListener myOnClickListener;
    private static ArrayList<Integer> removedItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myOnClickListener = new MyOnClickListener(this);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        data = new ArrayList<DataModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < MyData.nameArray.length; i++) {
            data.add(new DataModel(
                    MyData.nameArray[i],
                    MyData.versionArray[i],
                    MyData.id_[i],
                    MyData.drawableArray[i]
            ));
        }

        removedItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        adapter = new CustomAdapter(data);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    private static class MyOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

        private final Context context;

        private MyOnClickListener(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            removeItem(v);
        }

        private void removeItem(View v) {
            int selectedItemPosition = recyclerView.getChildPosition(v);
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder
                    = recyclerView.findViewHolderForPosition(selectedItemPosition);
            TextView textViewName
                    = (TextView) viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            String selectedName = (String) textViewName.getText();
            int selectedItemId = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < MyData.nameArray.length; i++) {
                if (selectedName.equals(MyData.nameArray[i])) {
                    selectedItemId = MyData.id_[i];
                }
            }
            removedItems.add(selectedItemId);
            data.remove(selectedItemPosition);
            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(selectedItemPosition);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.add_item) {
           //check if any items to add
            if (removedItems.size() != 0) {
                addRemovedItemToList();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Nothing to add", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void addRemovedItemToList() {
        int addItemAtListPosition = 3;
        data.add(addItemAtListPosition, new DataModel(
                MyData.nameArray[removedItems.get(0)],
                MyData.versionArray[removedItems.get(0)],
                MyData.id_[removedItems.get(0)],
                MyData.drawableArray[removedItems.get(0)]
        ));
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(addItemAtListPosition);
        removedItems.remove(0);
    }
}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<DataModel> dataSet;

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textViewName;
        TextView textViewVersion;
        ImageView imageViewIcon;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            this.textViewVersion = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewVersion);
            this.imageViewIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<DataModel> data) {
        this.dataSet = data;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.cards_layout, parent, false);

        view.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.myOnClickListener);

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

        TextView textViewName = holder.textViewName;
        TextView textViewVersion = holder.textViewVersion;
        ImageView imageView = holder.imageViewIcon;

        textViewName.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getName());
        textViewVersion.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getVersion());
        imageView.setImageResource(dataSet.get(listPosition).getImage());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }
}
```

DataModel.java

```
public class DataModel {

    String name;
    String version;
    int id_;
    int image;

    public DataModel(String name, String version, int id_, int image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.version = version;
        this.id_ = id_;
        this.image=image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id_;
    }
}
```

MyData.java

```
public class MyData {

    static String[] nameArray = {"Cupcake", "Donut", "Eclair", "Froyo", "Gingerbread", "Honeycomb", "Ice Cream Sandwich","JellyBean", "Kitkat", "Lollipop", "Marshmallow"};
    static String[] versionArray = {"1.5", "1.6", "2.0-2.1", "2.2-2.2.3", "2.3-2.3.7", "3.0-3.2.6", "4.0-4.0.4", "4.1-4.3.1", "4.4-4.4.4", "5.0-5.1.1","6.0-6.0.1"};

    static Integer[] drawableArray = {R.drawable.cupcake, R.drawable.donut, R.drawable.eclair,
            R.drawable.froyo, R.drawable.gingerbread, R.drawable.honeycomb, R.drawable.ics,
            R.drawable.jellybean, R.drawable.kitkat, R.drawable.lollipop,R.drawable.marsh};

    static Integer[] id_ = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView friendsListView = findViewById(R.id.friendListView);

        final ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new Item(R.drawable.abc, "Item1"));
        items.add(new Item(R.drawable.def, "Item2"));


        ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, items);

        ListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        friendsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello " + items.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```