# how to insert Image from gallery to a EditTex View?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am on a Notetaking project where I want to allow users to insert images in their notes. the image will be on top or below of texts. this is the code by which I am trying to get the image into the editText field. But after selecting the image it does not show in the edit Text. it will be very helpful if anybody can help me.
this is in my **onCreate**:

```
            img = findViewById(R.id.addImage);
            LinearLayout layoutCustomization = findViewById(R.id.miscellaneous_layout);
            initialCustomizationOption(layoutCustomization);

            mGetImg = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(), new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(Uri result) {
                    uriImg = result;
                    try {
                        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(InsertActivity.this.getContentResolver(), uriImg);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
            ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(InsertActivity.this,bitmap,0);

            SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
            builder.append(binding.noteData.getText());


            String imgId = "[img=1]";

            int selStart = binding.noteData.getSelectionStart();
            builder.replace(binding.noteData.getSelectionStart(), binding.noteData.getSelectionEnd(), imgId);
            builder.setSpan(imageSpan, selStart, selStart + imgId.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            binding.noteData.setText(builder);
```

this is my XML:

```
            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/noteData"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bg"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/product_sans_regular"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:hint="Notes..."
                    android:overScrollMode="always"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Comment: The image should be inserted to an [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView) widget but not to an Edittext which is used for capturing user's text input.

Comment: @Tonnie thanks for your answer. Is there any way I can Insert an image above or below of a text? If I put an image view there then the previous image will be replaced rather than adding a new image.

Comment: Single `ImageView` only presents a picture at a time. You may need a `ListView` to present more than one picture. Please take a look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54992231/2828685

Comment: @A.K.MMUHIBULLAHNAYEM if my answer worked ,please mark as answer . if you think I really put some effort into it , thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image will show in `image view` , if you want to upload image from gallery then this code will work

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.style.ImageSpan;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;

public class TestImage extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView img;
    TextView textView;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    private Uri filePath;
    private Bitmap bitmap;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_image);

        img = findViewById(R.id.addImage);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textview);
        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                if (getApplicationContext() != null && getApplicationContext().getPackageName().equals(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)){
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            switch (requestCode) {

                case PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST:
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        //data gives you the image uri. Try to convert that to bitmap
                        filePath = data.getData();
                        try {
                            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(TestImage.this.getContentResolver(), filePath);
                            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        break;
                    } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                        Log.e("TestImage", "Selecting picture cancelled");
                    }
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TestImage", "Exception in onActivityResult : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Layout will be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".TestImage"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250sp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:id="@+id/addImage"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Here is your text"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:id="@+id/textview"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```